# Loading external content into server on localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dynamic-data

I am trying to create a web application that loads content dynamically. When I do this, of course I want to do the development locally, i.e. localhost. Some of the "functionality" is a form and when posting that form an e-mail is sent from the server. Because I want to access the servers e-mail functionality, I am linking that specific page to the server. But the problem is that it is not loaded.

In my script below it works, but if I change the comments so I am pointing to iandapp.com, than I just get empty string. It's exactly the same page, just copied it to the server.

```
$("#support").click(function () {
    if(support_page==null){
       //$("#section2").load("http://www.iandapp.com/smic/subscription_2.php", function(data) {
       $("#section2").load("subscription_2.php", function(data) {
           support_page = data;
       });
    }
```

The script is located inte the main page (index.html) and content should be loaded into a div with id="section2".

I know that (support_page==null) is true because I have a break point inside where it stops.

Please let me know what the probelm is and how I can fix it. I have been going on for hours trying to get this working.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

google about

> cross domain ajax requests

. This is disabled in the browser level. There are ways to circumvent this, both client side and server side.

Answer (score 0):

It probably has something to do with it being a cross-domain request. You could use what I consider to be a "hack", http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/, but I.M.O. it's not worth it.

Have you considered sending through an SMTP server instead? If so, you'd have no problem with the file (sending the mail) being local.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.getJSON()` instead of `.load()`, this [method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) supports cross-domain requests. You'll need to make sure your PHP script does something like the following:

```
echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($results) . ')';
```

jQuery will append something like `?callback=callback0234` to the request url because it wants you to 'call' the callback function when your script returns. So the output of your script may look something like:

```
callback0234('mydata': '<p>This is my data</p>')
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work. I changed to $.getJSON("http://iandapp.com/smic/subscription_2.php", function(data) and also tried with $.(#support"). Getting "ReferenceError: data is not defined". Is my way of calling getJson incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

And what about adding proper headers on server's http response to allow crossdomain ?

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Origin: *
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it like this without success:

<?php  header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');?>

<?php  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');?>

<?php  header('Access-Control-Origin: *');?>

Doesn't work. Actually, I don't see the headers in firebug, but it should, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes you should see headers with firebug when calling your subscription_2.php

Comment: The wildcard value for Access-Control-Allow-Origin would not work with Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true. Please try adding only Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * to the header and see if it works for you. Here's a detailed explanation on the headers:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS.